# How to convert an object with arrays into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have a problem in reducing an object which contains array into a simple array. I have a backend which returns a list of dogs and their price. The way the api returns the data, seems really difficult to work with and I am struggling to convert the object into an array. I have tried turning into an array and reducing it.

Here is an example - I want to convert the following object:

```
const a = {
    dogs: [{
            "id": "dog1",
            "priceRange": [
                "low",
                "high"
            ],
            "vaccinated": true,
        },
        {
            "id": "dog2",
            "priceRange": [
                "low",
                "high"
            ],
            "vaccinated": false,
        }
    ],
    "cost": [{
            "id": "low",
            "cost": 200,
        },
        {
            "id": "mid",
            "cost": 400,
        },
        {
            "id": "high",
            "cost": 600,
        }
    ]
};
```

into this array:

```
const reducedArray = [{
        "id": "dog1",
        "priceRange": [{
                "id": "low",
                "cost": 200,
            },
            {
                "id": "high",
                "cost": 600,
            }
        ],
        "vaccinated": true,
    },
    {
        "id": "dog2",
        "priceRange": [{
                "id": "low",
                "cost": 200,
            },
            {
                "id": "high",
                "cost": 600,
            }
        ],
        "vaccinated": false,
    }
]
```

I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your `a.dogs` array first and within each iteration, also iterate over the priceRange array and find its corresponding value inside the `a.cost` array and return that instead of the string low or high.

```
a.dogs.map(dog => ({
    ...dog,
  priceRange: dog.priceRange.map(priceRange => a.cost.find(cost => cost.id === priceRange))
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over `a.cost` while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the key is the `id` and value is the object
- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate over `a.dogs` and set the `priceRannge` items from the Map using another `Array#map` iteraion

```js
const a = {
  "dogs": [ { "id": "dog1", "priceRange": [  "low", "high" ], "vaccinated": true }, { "id": "dog2", "priceRange": [ "low", "high" ], "vaccinated": false } ],
  "cost": [ { "id": "low", "cost": 200 }, { "id": "mid", "cost": 400 }, { "id": "high", "cost": 600 } ]
};

const costMap = a.cost.reduce((map, cost) => 
  map.set(cost.id, cost)
, new Map);

const reducedArray = a.dogs.map(dog => ({
  ...dog, 
  priceRange: dog.priceRange.map(range => {
    const { id, cost } = costMap.get(range) || {};
    return { id, cost};
  })
}));

console.log(reducedArray);
```